# Use latest build tools version automatically?

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-tools

I find that if I do not explicitly specify *buildToolsVersion* in *build.gradle*, it will use a very old version even if I have since uninstalled it.  I must manually specify the version to have it use the latest.  Is there a way to have it always use the latest without having to manually update *buildToolsVersion* in every project?